# Getting only positive values for latitude and longitude with iso60709 Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

When I run the following code the negative sign get's removed for some reason and I always end up with a positive latitude and longitude.

Code:

```
def extract_reduced_accuracy_lat_long(location):
    if location:
        loc = Location(location)
        print("location is")
        print(loc)
        lat = round(float(loc.lat.degrees), 1)
        lng = round(float(loc.lng.degrees), 1)
        return lat, lng
    else:
        return None, None



lat, long = extract_reduced_accuracy_lat_long("-40.20361-40.20361")
print(lat)
print(long)
```

output:

```
location is
<iso6709.iso6709.Location object at 0x7fc37447ae10>
40.2
40.2
```

Any idea why this is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to wrap in parentheses your coordinates like this:

```
lat, long = extract_reduced_accuracy_lat_long([-40.20361, -40.20361])
```

Comment: I get a Type error. 
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Could you send a definition of the "Location" class or post a complete script somewhere?

Comment: I guess you can try to replace your coordinate points string to "-40.20361,-40.20361" or "-40.20361;-40.20361". Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

You must use brackets to contain your coordinate points. This way it is taking two points at arguments, separated by a comma. Like so:

```
lat,long=extract_reduced_accuracy_lat_long([-40.20361,-40.20361])
```

Comment: I get a Type error. 
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`